# Pandas - Reading different sets of data in 1 csv file

Tags: python, pandas

My CSV File: (Between Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday are empty cell blocks)

```
Monday          Tuesday         Wednesday
Items   Price   Items   Price   Items   Price
Mon     1       Tues    1       Wed     1
Mon2    2       Tues2   2       Wed2    2
```

How can I read a specific table?

The outcome that I want:

```
df['Monday']
>>
Items   Price
Mon     1
Mon2    2

df['Tuesday']['Items'].values()
>>
['Tues', 'Tues2']
```

Is this possible?

Comment: _Is this possible?_ Yes. What have you tried? Have you done any research?

Comment: df = pd.read_csv("Assignment2/menu2.csv", header=[0,1], index_col=0) With this, I can successfully do df['Monday']['Items'], but unfortuantely, I am unable to do df['Monday']['Price']

Answer (score 0):

If you are using.read_csv of pandas you can specify the column header

```
 #exemple file 2 lines of headers:
 df=pd.read_csv('filename', header=[0, 1])
```

Source:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html